# iot edge direct method handler in python

Tags: python, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have created a module for a Bacnet scan and it will respond with a list of devices and its address as a result. But I'm having trouble implementing a direct method handler in python. When i first tried implementing it myself i got this error. Which could mean I didn't successfully register the direct method callback. I have some references but it was from C# and azure docs is not helping me figure out the right method to register the callback. for IoTHubModuleClient there's a on_method_request_received and a receive_method_request. appreciate any help!

```
def iothub_client_scan_run():
try:
    iot_client = iothub_client_init()

    bacnet_scan_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=device_method_listener, args=(iot_client,))
    bacnet_scan_listener_thread.daemon = True
    bacnet_scan_listener_thread.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1000)
    
def device_method_listener(iot_client):
 while True:
        # Receive the direct method request
    method_request = iot_client.receive_method_request()
    
    print (
        "\nMethod callback called with:\nmethodName = {method_name}\npayload = {payload}".format(
            method_name=method_request.name,
            payload=method_request.payload
        )
    )
    if method_request.name == "runBacnetScan":
        response = bacnet_scan_device(method_request)
    else:
        response_payload = {"Response": "Direct method {} not defined".format(method_request.name)}
        response_status = 404
            
    # Send a method response indicating the method request was resolved
    print('Sending method response')
    iot_client.send_method_response(response)
    print('Message sent!')
```

[image]

Edit:
Here is my route config
[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/sync-samples/receive_direct_method.py)? It uses the device client, but a module client should have the same `on_method_request_received` property to assign a method handler to.

Comment: I just tried that one as well. But it still returns the same error. I can't run it locally to test so I always deploy it to the device first. i wonder if my route is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue or at least find the root cause and it was my network configuration under the createOptions. It seems like there's an issue when I'm trying to do NetworkMode: host and connects to the IotModuleClient.connect_from_edge_environment via connect with connection string. I'm still trying to tweak the connection configuration but at least i know its not on the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    async def method_request_handler(module_client):
        while  True:
            method_request = await module_client.receive_method_request()
            print (
                "\nMethod callback called with:\nmethodName = {method_name}\npayload = {payload}".format(
                    method_name=method_request.name,
                    payload=method_request.payload
                )
            )
            if method_request.name == "method1":
                payload = {"result": True, "data": "some data"}  # set response payload
                status = 200  # set return status code
                print("executed method1")
            elif method_request.name == "method2":
                payload = {"result": True, "data": 1234}  # set response payload
                status = 200  # set return status code
                print("executed method2")
            else:
                payload = {"result": False, "data": "unknown method"}  # set response payload
                status = 400  # set return status code
                print("executed unknown method: " + method_request.name)
                    
            # Send the response
            method_response = MethodResponse.create_from_method_request(method_request, status, payload)
            await module_client.send_method_response(method_response)
            print('Message sent!')

    def stdin_listener():
        while True:
            try:
                selection = input("Press Q to quit\n")
                if selection == "Q" or selection == "q":
                    print("Quitting...")
                    break
            except:
                time.sleep(10)

    # Schedule task for C2D Listener
    listeners = asyncio.gather(input1_listener(module_client), twin_patch_listener(module_client), method_request_handler(module_client))
```