# Azure edge modules cannot receive direct method requests

Tags: python, azure-iot-edge

I have created a very small edge module which sends telemetry to an IoT Hub and which receives direct messages. When I start my IoT Edge script with

```
IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string)
```

locally everything is fine. It can send telemetry and receive direct method requests.

When I deploy my script as an edge module in a container it also sends telemetry, but however it cannot receive any direct method requests:

```
IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()
```

My stripped code would look like this:

```
import time
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import threading
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from azure.iot.device import MethodResponse

async def main():

    try:
        if not sys.version >= "3.5.3":
            raise Exception( "The sample requires python 3.5.3+. Current version of Python: %s" % sys.version )
        print ( "IoT Hub Client for Python" )

        # For production
        module_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()

        # For tests
        #connection_string = "Here was my connection string :)"
        #module_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string)
        
        async def direct_method_received(method_request):

            try:
                await module_client.send_message("Received Method Request: " + str(method_request.name))                
                print("Received direct message: {} {}\n".format(str(method_request.name), str(method_request.payload)))
       
                method_response = MethodResponse.create_from_method_request(method_request, 200, None)
                await module_client.send_method_response(method_response)
                
            except Exception as e:            
                method_response = MethodResponse.create_from_method_request(method_request, 400, payload=logging)
                await module_client.send_method_response(method_response)


        module_client.on_method_request_received = direct_method_received
        
        await module_client.connect()
        await module_client.send_message("Receive Module is running.")

        while True:
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error: {}".format(str(e)))

    except Exception as e:
        print("Unexpected error %s \n" % e)
        raise
    finally:        
        await module_client.shutdown()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The iotedge service says that my module is working fine. Also as I said, it sends telemetry which I can receive in the IoT hub.
The direct method request is sent with the portal, directly in the edge module controls:

[image]

The error is

[image]

That confuses me because it is working when I directly connect to my device without edge runtime.

Here it is said that you need some specific network configuration, but I don't know how to do it and also I don't know if that is the problem in my case.

[iot edge direct method handler in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865673/iot-edge-direct-method-handler-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I could get the sample running :-)
Could you check if you reference `azure-iot-device~=2.5.1` in you requirements.txt?

From https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/releases I see that v2.3.0 fixed this:

- Added handlers for receive method request

  - Deprecated receive method request API

René

Comment: That totally makes sense. The versions of my local python environment and my container were different and I updated to 2.5.1. I now receive the direct method requests in my module. Sorry for that.
As a general advice for people who step into problems with modules, check the "requirements.txt" of your module as it does not get auto generated with the newest versions of packages. In my case I just used the auto generated requirements list of Visual Studio Code without further looking into it and didn't have this on my mind at all.